# Vertical distances of the three layers of the Darklands

Tags: pathfinder-1e, darklands

The group I am GMing may plan to go down deep into the Darklands. They are in [Nar-Voth](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Nar-Voth) already and might want to go all the way down to [Orv](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Orv) through the [Endless Gulf](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Endless_Gulf). How deep is this thing? (vertically from the [Court of Ether](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Court_of_Ether) in Nar-Voth to the [Midnight Mountains](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Midnight_Mountains) in Orv)

As of now, I only found, that the Midnight Mountains are two miles high on average, and the ceiling is a further two miles above the tallest peak.

Are there any sources that describe how deep under the surface the three layers of the Darklands are? (Nar-Voth, [Sekamina](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Midnight_Mountains) and Orv)

In case there aren't official sources: What would be meaningful vertical coordinates for the three layers?

**Oops.** I just found out the answers (more or less). Here are the distances from the surface:

- Nar-Voth (as Yohann V mentioned): about 2,000 ft.
- Sekamina (from the pathfinderwiki page): about 2,000ft – 8,000 ft.
- Orv (derived from the values given about the Midnight Mountains): about 18,500 ft – 22,000 ft

I think these values would make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't comment but from [PathfinderWiki](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Nar-Voth) :

> Nar-Voth is the uppermost region of the Darklands, loosely defined as descending from the surface of Golarion to a depth of about 2000 feet.

2000 feet ~ 0.37878 miles